# Problem Explanation & Bug Detection (Suppose I want to print prime numbers between 3-8 )

Tags: c, loops

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, c;
    for (i = 3; i <= 8; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 8; j++)
            if (i % j != 0) {

            }

    }
    for (i = 3; i <= 8; i++) {

        for (j = i + 1; j < 8; j++) {
            printf("%d\n", i);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I assume that 1st `i` will be `3` and `j` will check it can be divided by `j` until `8` . I know I am talking about wrong things may be it is quite illogical. But I am stucks. Please explain.

Comment: Rizwan Alam Shaon What is the question?

Comment: If `j` is always larger than `i`, then you need to divide `j` by `i`.

Comment: The code has no "bugs"as such, it just doesn't do anything very useful.

Comment: I want to know why it can't print prime numbers between 3-8 rather than printing other things.

Comment: @WeatherVane The code does not make sense. So it is unclear what to explain.:)

Comment: There are loads of examples about prime numbers available.

Comment: The code give the impression of being randomly copied code lines, like something written after briefly seeing a correct solution. The task of printing a few primes also is likely to be a homework assignment. Please understand that under in this situation "why it can't print prime numbers between 3-8?" as a question lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying this yourself. Please describe how the shown code maps to your understanding of how to find primes by using pen and paper. That should already help, otherwise it is the foundation for getting help here.

Comment: Generally helpful reading in case of homework-related questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, c;
    for (i = 3; i <= 8; i++) {
        bool prime = true;
        for (j = 2; j < i-1; j++) 
            if (i % j == 0) 
                prime = false;
        if (prime)printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is very likely exactly what OP wants, something which can be handed in as homework. It is however not a good answer. For that it lacks explanation. Whether giving a code solution (explained or not) is an actual helpful answer is a matter of opinion. In my opinion it is not.

Comment: @ArdentCoder: C89 is more than 30 years old. `bool` was introduced in C99, which is more than 20 years old. Using `int isPrime = 1;`, which you did in your answer, is arguably far less readable than `bool isPrime = true;`. Also, nitpicking about `stdbool.h` is a bit weird since your answer also isn't valid C. It doesn't include `<stdio.h>`. It doesn't declare `i` nor `j`. It doesn't even contain a function.

Comment: @Groo My answer was meant to correct the logical part of OP's code which had the necessary headers and declarations. I had mentioned it in my answer: "Problems in *your algorithm*". If I had redeclared those `i` and `j`, it would have been an error.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

The *i-loop* checks the numbers from 3 to 8.

The *j-loop* should run numbers from 2 to *i* and check if any of those numbers is a factor of *i*. If so then *i* is not a prime number.

**Problems in your algorithm:**

1. You have got the *i-loop* correct. But your *j-loop* is running in vain.
2. You should check if `j` is a factor of `i` in order to determine if `i` is not a prime number. So you should change that if-statement to `if (i % j == 0)`. You should also have a flag to store this information.

**Solution:**

```
// Flag to check if i is a prime number
int isPrime; 
// Run numbers from 3 to 8
for (i = 3; i <= 8; ++i)
{
    // Let us assume that i is prime
    isPrime = 1; 
    // Check if i is divisible by any number other than 1 and i
    for (j = 2; j < i; ++j)
    {
        // If j is a factor of i then i is not a prime number
        if (i % j == 0)
        {
            isPrime = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Print i if it is prime
    if (isPrime)
    {
        printf("\n%d", i);
    }
}
```

**Bonus:**

Mathematically, it is enough to iterate j from 2 to sqrt(i). It is not necessary here because these are small numbers.

Comment: If you do provide a (nicely explained) code solution, then be so kind not to create a trap for anybody handing it in as homework. Make sure that it does not have warning or errors during compiling. I.e. it should basically match the rules of a [mre]. Also, just in case you are not aware, please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions